# Extract attributes for markers in leaflet, onClick event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using a JSON file to plot the markers in Leaflet:

```
 [{
"id": 1,
"date": "1/1/2015",
"Title": "Trinity College",
"Latitude": 41.745167,
"Longitude": -72.69263}, 
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "1/2/2015",
    "Title": "Wesleyan University",
    "Latitude": 41.55709,
    "Longitude": -72.65691
  },{...}]
```

What I'm doing is the following:

```
      var markers = new L.markerClusterGroup(); //clustering function

  var markerList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonDataObject.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].Latitude), parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].Longitude)));
    marker.bindPopup(jsonDataObject[i].Title );
    markerList.push(marker);
      }
      markers.addLayers(markerList);
      map.addLayer(markers);
```

However because I'll add extra functionalities for each individual markers, I want to add 'click' event for each marker and in this function accessing the JSON attributes for each marker. For example:

```
marker.on('click', onClick_Marker)

function onClick_Marker(e) {
        popup = L.popup()
        .setContent("The number id is: " + e.id)
        .openOn(map);
    }
```

How to get access individual attributes, from the JSON file, in a pop-up window?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already create a Popup for each Marker, you could already embed your JSON data into its content.

But if for whatever reason you cannot do it, you just have to *reference* your JSON data from your created Leaflet Markers, as described in:

[Leaflet: Including metadata with CircleMarkers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012510/leaflet-including-metadata-with-circlemarkers/50019000#50019000)

Within your loop, use any of the 3 described methods to attach your `jsonDataObject[i]` to your `marker`.

Then in your `"click"` handler, your clicked Marker is accessible as `e.target`, then depending on how you attached your JSON data, you can retrieve it with `e.target.myJsonData`, `e.target.options.myJsonData` or `e.target.getProps().myJsonData`.

For example:

```js
var jsonDataObject = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "1/1/2015",
    "Title": "Trinity College",
    "Latitude": 41.745167,
    "Longitude": -72.69263
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "1/2/2015",
    "Title": "Wesleyan University",
    "Latitude": 41.55709,
    "Longitude": -72.65691
  }
];

var map = L.map('map').setView([41.65, -72.67], 9);

for (var i = 0; i < jsonDataObject.length; i++) {
  var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].Latitude), parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].Longitude)));
  marker.bindPopup(jsonDataObject[i].Title, {
    autoClose: false
  });
  map.addLayer(marker);
  marker.on('click', onClick_Marker)
  // Attach the corresponding JSON data to your marker:
  marker.myJsonData = jsonDataObject[i];
}

function onClick_Marker(e) {
  var marker = e.target;
  popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(marker.getLatLng())
    .setContent("The number id is: " + marker.myJsonData.id)
    .openOn(map);
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```