# Accessing Leaflet Marker Meta properties on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In my leaflet map when a user clicks on a marker it populates a table elsewhere in the page with a table of attribute fields. I want to also have a button that would allow the user to delete the marker from the map. To do this I am aiming to write the **current feature id and layer name** to global variables whenever a scheme is clicked. This will then be used by the button to remove the selected feature from the map.

How do I retrieve these ***meta attributes*** from a marker click event? I can retrieve the attribute information easily as shown below:

```
layer.on('click', function (e) {
globalVariable  = e.feature.properties.name
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract attributes for markers in leaflet, onClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856635/extract-attributes-for-markers-in-leaflet-onclick-event)

Comment: Tagged a dupe that might help

Comment: HI there - thanks for flagging but unfortunately still doesn't show how to access the attributes of feature / layer id or the respective layer name

Comment: OK. There's an internal method `stamp(obj)` which returns the internal ID - does that help?

Comment: That solves the feature ID - thanks very much! Now just need to work out how to get the layer

Comment: If your objective is to save something so you can remove the marker from the map, saving the marker object would be the obvious thing.

Comment: So the marker will already be in the map - i need to work out how to make a generic button that will be created on marker click that will have the option to remove the clicked marker from the map. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the marker object on click:

```
layer.on('click', function(e) {
     clickedMarker = e.target;
});
```

Then you can simply use

```
clickedMarker.removeFrom(map);
```

or one if its variants after checking that `clickedMarker` is actually a marker and is currently on the map.